# R data.table merge tables grouping by multiple columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two huge data tables (`dt1` and `dt2`) that are almost identical except for 1 column. I want to join the tables by the `p-1` columns, where `p <- ncol(dt1)`. Should I `setkey()` to the `p-1` columns and join using `dt1[dt2]`? If that is the case, how can I enter the arguments in `setkey()` since I can't put quoted string as argument.

Here is some simulated data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(260), 10, 26))
setnames(dt1, letters)
dt2 <- copy(dt1)
dt2[,z:=rnorm(10)]

## Sections below won't run
setkey(dt1, get(letters[-which(letters=="z")]))
setkey(dt2, get(letters[-which(letters=="z")]))
dt1[dt2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setkeyv`:

```
setkeyv(dt1, letters[-which(letters=="z")])
setkeyv(dt2, letters[-which(letters=="z")])
dt1[dt2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the different column this works

```
merge(dt1,dt2,names(dt1)[-grep("z",names(dt1))])
```

It also preserves the two original differing columns as `dt$z.x` and `dt$z.y`